# F#, Serialize dynamically generated objects with WebAPI

Tags: f#, asp.net-web-api2

I am attempting to create Web API controller in F# which returns objects from Entity Framework. SharpObject and SharpContext are my object and DbContext respectively defined in a c# project.

```
/// Retrieves values.
[<RoutePrefix("api2/values")>]
type ValuesController() = 
    inherit ApiController()
    let values = [| "value1"; "value2" |]

    /// Gets all values.
    [<Route("")>]
    member x.Get() : IEnumerable<SharpObject> = 
        use context = new SharpContext()
        context.SharpObjects.ToList() :> IEnumerable<SharpObject>
```

Here is SharpObject with the SerializableAttribute.

```
[Serializable]
public class SharpObject
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The error that I am getting is this:
`The type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SharpObject_3A697B5C46C0BF76858FEAFC93BFED36DD8D4CA2CEACBB178D2D3C38BB2D2052 was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.`

When I de-compile this using ILSpy, it looks like this:

```
[Route("")]
public IEnumerable<SharpObject> Get()
{
    SharpContext context = new SharpContext();
    IEnumerable<SharpObject> result;
    try
    {
        result = (IEnumerable<SharpObject>)context.SharpObjects.ToList<SharpObject>();
    }
    finally
    {
        IDisposable disposable = context as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

What is the best way to get my list to show through in f#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the object that you get from EF is *not*, in fact, of type `SharpObject`, but rather of that scarily named type, which *inherits* from `SharpObject`. This type is called "proxy" and is dynamically generated by EF in order to provide certain services (such as lazy loading, see below).

Because your action is declared as returning `IEnumerable<SharpObject>`, the default WebAPI's XML serializer expects to find object of that type, and so rightly complains upon finding an object of different type.

One temporary, bandaid-style fix that you can try is to remove the `virtual` keywords from your entity (why do you have them there, anyway?). It is the presence of the `virtual` keywords that causes EF to generate the proxy type. Absent `virtual`, no proxy will be generated, thus making the XML serializer happy.
This, however, will not work once you extend your model to include navigation properties with lazy loading. Those properties, you *must* make virtual, otherwise lazy loading won't work.

So the *correct* fix is **not to use the same type for both DB-facing DTO and client-facing DTO**. Use different types.
Using the same type for these two purposes may seem "convenient" at first, but this road quickly leads to numerous problems. One of small technical problems you have already discovered. But even absent those, conceptually, you almost never, ever want to just serve up your DB records directly to the untrusted user. Some of possible consequences include security holes, badly factored UI code, badly factored database structure, performance problems, and so on.

Bad idea. Don't do it.

P.S. This doesn't actually have anything to do with F#.